# cortana custom skill not working on Windows phone

Tags: bots, windows-10-mobile, azure-bot-service, cortana-skills-kit

I have created a custom cortana skill using bot frame work.My channel name or invocation phrase is "S********O".When I tried to invoke Cortana skill in Windows Phone, it doesn't invoke the skill. Instead, it keeps directing me to Bing results.

I invoke skill using Ask Keyword Ask "S********O"  and it redirects to bing search. Its is working fine in Andriod. Is anyone have idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons why you get directed to Bing instead of a skill.

1. The account you are using on the device is not the same one used for development (self publish / default settings)
2. Your region and/or language settings are not US / en-US in the App
3. The account you are using is an AAD joined account, not Microsoft account
4. You've discovered a bug

Comment: Also V3 of the Cortana app is buggy, use V2 of the app if you have that option.

Comment: And, if you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/known-issues, you will see that login on Cortana is broken on Windows Phone.